# Too many if statements, How can i take a whole bunch if statements that check 13 separate lists more optimally?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a 13 if statements that check 13 separate lists to check if a value is in that particular list. Now surely there's a better way of doing this because I'm going to have to do this 12 more times and that'll get messy.

```
  void Start()
{
    spline = GameObject.Find("Spline");
    SplinePath = spline.GetComponent<PathGenerator>();
    splineSplices = SplinePath.slices;
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    splineMesh = spline.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    trisLenght = splineMesh.triangles.Length;
    blocksObjects = new GameObject[trisLenght];

    //Lane 1
    for (int i = 0; i < trisLenght; i += 26)
    {
        lane1Index.Add(i);
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < trisLenght; i += 26)
    {
        lane2Index.Add(i);
    }

    //Lane 3
    for (int i = 4; i < trisLenght; i += 26)
    {
        lane3Index.Add(i);
    }

    for (int i = 6; i < trisLenght; i += 26)
    {
        lane4Index.Add(i);
    }

    //Lane 5
    for (int i = 8; i < trisLenght; i += 26)
    {
        lane5Index.Add(i);
    }

    for (int i = 10; i < trisLenght; i += 26)
    {
        lane6Index.Add(i);
    }

    for (int i = 12; i < trisLenght; i += 26)
    {
        lane7Index.Add(i);
    }

    for (int i = 14; i < trisLenght; i += 26)
    {
        lane8Index.Add(i);
    }

    for (int i = 16; i < trisLenght; i += 26)
    {
        lane9Index.Add(i);
    }

    for (int i = 18; i < trisLenght; i += 26)
    {
        lane10Index.Add(i);
    }

    for (int i = 20; i < trisLenght; i += 26)
    {
        lane11Index.Add(i);
    }

    for (int i = 22; i < trisLenght; i += 26)
    {
        lane12Index.Add(i);
    }

    for (int i = 24; i < trisLenght; i += 26)
    {
        lane13Index.Add(i);
    }
}
  void Update()
{
    Vector3 prev_up = Player.transform.up;
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        //raycast down to get the triangle index that were currently on
        if (Physics.Raycast(Player.transform.position, -prev_up, out hit) && !GameObject.Find("TriParentA") && !GameObject.Find("TriParentB"))
        {
            CreateBlockOnLane13(hit.triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane1(hit.triangleIndex);

            if (audioPeer.audioBand64[2] > oldFrequency && audioPeer.audioBand64[2] > .5f)//Creates a new block to the beat
            {
                //pick a random index from 0 - 12
                int randomLane = Random.Range(1, 12);
                ChooseRandomLane(randomLane, hit.triangleIndex);


            }
             oldFrequency = audioPeer.audioBand64[2];
         }
    }
}

void ChooseRandomLane(int randomLane, int triangleIndex)
{
    switch (randomLane)
    {

        case 0://every other space
            CreateBlockOnLane13(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane11(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane9(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane7(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane5(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane3(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane1(triangleIndex);
        break;
        case 1://every other space 
            CreateBlockOnLane12(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane10(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane8(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane6(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane4(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane2(triangleIndex);
            break;
        case 2://5 gap in middle
            CreateBlockOnLane13(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane12(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane11(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane10(triangleIndex);

            CreateBlockOnLane4(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane2(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane3(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane1(triangleIndex);
            break;
        case 3://3 gap in middle
            CreateBlockOnLane13(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane12(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane11(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane10(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane9(triangleIndex);

            CreateBlockOnLane3(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane4(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane2(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane3(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane1(triangleIndex);
            break;
        case 4:
            CreateBlockOnLane13(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane12(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane11(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane10(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane9(triangleIndex);

            CreateBlockOnLane3(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane4(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane2(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane3(triangleIndex);
            CreateBlockOnLane1(triangleIndex); break;
        case 5:
            CreateBlockOnLane7(triangleIndex);
            break;
        case 6:
            CreateBlockOnLane8(triangleIndex);
            break;
        case 7:
            CreateBlockOnLane9(triangleIndex);
            break;
        case 8:
            CreateBlockOnLane10(triangleIndex);
             break;
        case 9:
            CreateBlockOnLane11(triangleIndex);
            break;
        case 10:
            CreateBlockOnLane12(triangleIndex);
        break;

    }
}
    void CreateBlockOnLane13(int triangleIndex)
{
    if (lane1Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 1;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1168); //+=26
    }

    if (lane2Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 2;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1166); //+=26
    }

    if (lane3Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 3;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1164); //+=26
    }

    if (lane4Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 4;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1162); //+=26
    }

    if (lane5Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 5;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1160); //+=26
    }

    if (lane6Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 6;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1158); //+=26
    }

    if (lane7Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 7;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1156); //+=26
    }

    if (lane8Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 8;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1154); //+=26
    }

    if (lane9Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 9;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1152); //+=26
    }

    if (lane10Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 10;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1150); //+=26
    }

    if (lane11Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 11;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1148); //+=26
    }

    if (lane12Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 12;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1146); //+=26
    }

    if (lane13Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 13;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1144); //+=26
    }
}
 void CreateBlockOnLane12(int triangleIndex)
{
    distribution = 5;

    if (lane1Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 1;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1166); //+=26
    }

    if (lane2Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 2;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1164); //+=26
    }

    if (lane3Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 3;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1162); //+=26
    }

    if (lane4Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 4;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1160); //+=26
    }

    if (lane5Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 5;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1158); //+=26
    }

    if (lane6Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 6;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1156); //+=26
    }

    if (lane7Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 7;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1154); //+=26
    }

    if (lane8Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 8;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1152); //+=26
    }

    if (lane9Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 9;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1150); //+=26
    }

    if (lane10Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 10;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1148); //+=26
    }

    if (lane11Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 11;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1146); //+=26
    }

    if (lane12Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 12;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1144); //24
    }

    if (lane13Index.Contains(triangleIndex))
    {
        currentLane = 13;
        SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + 1142); //24
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some context for what these lists represent or how you populate them in the first place? We might be able to create a better lookup structure inside that process.

Comment: I added the code for they get populated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your construction, you don't need to search your lists at all. You can compute the lane number directly by examining the index:

```
int TriangleIndexToLane(int triangleIndex) {
    return (triangleIndex >> 1) % 13 + 1;
}
```

Then your creation method simplifies to:

```
void CreateBlock(int triangleIndex, int laneOffset) {
    currentLane = TriangleIndexToLane(triangleIndex);
    int offset = 1144 + 2 * (laneOffset - currentLane);
    SpawnBlockAtIndex(triangleIndex + offset);
}
```

And your various switch cases become:

```
void ChooseRandomLane(int randomLane, int triangleIndex)
{
    switch (randomLane)
    {
    case 0://every other space
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 13);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 11);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 9);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 7);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 5);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 3);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 1);
    break;
    case 1://every other space 
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 12);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 10);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 8);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 6);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 4);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 2);
        break;
    case 2://5 gap in middle
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 13);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 12);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 11);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 10);

        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 4);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 3);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 2);
        CreateBlock(triangleIndex, 1);
        break;
    ...
```

Comment: Personally, I think this is a recipe for spaghetti.

Comment: @Evorlor I don't disagree. I think the strategy of deciding where to spawn objects by triangle index is itself a recipe for trouble, and I think a well-structured solution to the root problem would involve a larger refactor than we have visibility to offer here. At least this is *dense* spaghetti with far fewer moving parts to go wrong or coordinate changes between. ;)

Comment: with this id still have to check TriangleIndexToLane = to other lanes, in which id still have alot if statements right? its just not using the list.

Comment: @BigDuke6 the example above performs the same operations as your example `CreateBlockOnLane13`, with no if statements. Where do you think you would need to add some, to accomplish what additional functionality?

Comment: I have to check which lane the player is on and create blocks on a certain index based off of the players raycast hit.triangleIndex, so id have to check if the player is on a certain lane and create a block at a certain location based on the players location.

Comment: @DMGregory I've added some more code to my question to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do overall

Comment: The same principle applies - see the edit. Remember the [DRY principle: "don't repeat yourself."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) If you find yourself writing many versions of a function that differ only by some numbers, that's probably a job for variables / data, not code. Extract the common rule and code that.

Answer (score 1):

May be have list of LaneXIndex itself and use foreach or for loop

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you mean to make another list?